# Serving static files from Sinatra with case-insensitive URLs

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I'm serving a static site (generated by Jekyll/Octopress) on Heroku, using the thin webserver and a basic Sinatra app. My goal is to support case-insensitive URLs (either by serving the same page from URLs that vary by case, or by redirect/rewrite).

E.g. `http:/mysite/Hello.html` and `http://mysite/hello.html` should both serve the same file.

Here's the `config.ru` (from [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) distrib):

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'rack'
require 'rack/rewrite'

# The project root directory
$root = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)

class SinatraStaticServer < Sinatra::Base  

  get(/.+/) do
    send_sinatra_file(request.path) {404}
  end

  not_found do
    send_sinatra_file('404.html') {"Sorry, I cannot find #{request.path}"}
  end

  def send_sinatra_file(path, &missing_file_block)
    file_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public',  path)
    file_path = File.join(file_path, 'index.html') unless file_path =~ /\.[a-z]+$/i  
    File.exist?(file_path) ? send_file(file_path) : missing_file_block.call
  end

end

run SinatraStaticServer
```

Is there a way to do this using Rack or Sinatra? So far the furthest I've got is down-casing all files and using `.downcase` in `send_sinatra_file`.

Comment: Not to be rude, but have you actually tried it without anything special? I just tried it locally in a Sinatra app I have, and it served the desired file no matter how I capitalized it.

Comment: That's not rude. :) I've had some mixed results locally, but it fails on Heroku. e.g. http://davesquared.net/categories/HASKELL/ vs. http://davesquared.net/categories/haskell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea for your routing:

```
get '/' do
  send_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public', 'index.html'))
end

get '*' do
  file_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public',  request.path.downcase)
  File.exist?(file_path) ? send_file(file_path) : halt 404
end

not_found do
  send_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public', '404.html'))
end
```

This is untested, since I probably won't be able to reproduce your environment anyways. But I think that it would work for your purpose, assuming all your pages are lowercase (as you mentioned) and that you also have an actual `404.html` page.

Comment: Thanks. I tested with downcase (in my original `send_sinatra_file` method) and it works fine on Heroku. I was hoping there'd be a standard Rack module or something I could use, but I guess downcasing everything will be as good a solution as any.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the gem https://github.com/substancelab/route_downcaser. Very easy to use. It will convert all the routes sinatra receives into lowercase.

From the docs:

Just install gem
`gem install route_downcaser`

and then use after loading Sinatra

```rb
require 'route_downcaser'
use RouteDowncaser::DowncaseRouteMiddleware
```